# I want to calculate getters at Vuex. But its return NaN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am making game simulator studying JavaScript and Vue.

First, I call array of specific item from Json.

```
// json
[
    {
        "id": "10004",
        "damage": [
            50,
            60,
            65,
            70,
            75,
            80,
            85,
            90,
            95,
            100  <<--- get this
        ]
    },
]



// store/equip.js
export const state = () => ({
  chipF: [], // it's selectbox value
  chipS: []
});

export const getters = {
  getChipFDamage: state => {
    const chipF = state.chipF;
    return (chipF.damage[9]);  // return 100
  },

  getChipSDamage: state => {
    const chipS = state.chipS;
    return (chipS.damage[9]);  // return 100
  },
}

export const mutations = {
   ...chipF, chipS Mutation here
}
```

[image: looks like it is numbers.]

and I want summary this value

getChipFDamage + getChipSDamage = getDamage,

but "getDamage" returned NaN.
"getDamage" should be 200, but returned to NaN.

```
export const getters = {
  ....
  getDamage: getters => {
    return getters.getChipFDamage + getters.getChipFDamage // return NaN
    return parseInt(getters.getChipFDamage) + parseInt(getters.getChipFDamage) // return NaN
  }
}
```

I don't understand. Did I write something wrong?

If I write these getters in the vue file, they work correctly.

Comment: Try debugging first the value of chipF and chipS if you're getting the right values.

Comment: If chipF and chipS is undefined returned 0. Its same if damge is undefined. 0+0 also becomes a NaN.

Comment: What does your main store looks like

Comment: There is nothing in the main store. There is only one related to layout.

Comment: Then how do you store that on vuex?

Comment: I misunderstood. Located on the equip.js. module in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Add ' state ' it's work. But I don't know why

```
getDamage: (state, getters) => {
   return parseInt(getters.getChipFDamage) + parseInt(getters.getChipSDamage);
}
```

Comment: Because the order of the parameters matter i.e. the first parameter always refers to the store's `state`, the second refers to store's `getters` etc. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html. Your original function `getDamage` was just calling the first parameter `getters` but it still refers to the store's `state`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!